# Keen.io how to use savedQueries() to chart graph

Tags: javascript, keen-io

I'm trying to use savedQueries to draw graph without success.  Is savedQueries only used to CRUD queries in Keen or can it actually be used to chart graph as well?? Keys removed from the code, sorry for the inconvenience.

```
var client = new Keen({
  projectId: keen.project,
  writeKey: keen.writeKey,
  readKey: keen.readKey,
  masterKey: keen.masterKey
});
var savedQueries = client.savedQueries();
savedQueries.get("monthly-active-users", function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(response);
  var chart1 = new Keen.Dataviz()
    .el(document.getElementById('chart'))
    .chartType("area")
    .colors(["#6ab975"])
    .title("Monthly Active Users")
    .prepare();

  chart1
    .data(response)
    .render();
```

});

response obj from saved query

```
{
  "refresh_rate": 0,
  "user_last_modified_date": "2017-06-09T18:51:59.676000+00:00",
  "last_modified_date": "2017-06-09T18:51:59.676000+00:00",
  "query_name": "monthly-active-users",
  "urls": {
    "cached_query_url": "/3.0/projects/58f6fb8a90b3659264951b8d/queries/saved/monthly-active-users",
    "cached_query_results_url": "/3.0/projects/58f6fb8a90b3659264951b8d/queries/saved/monthly-active-users/result"
  },
  "created_date": "2017-04-25T23:52:45.685000+00:00",
  "query": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "operator": "ne",
        "property_name": "user_id",
        "property_value": "guest"
      },
      {
        "operator": "not_contains",
        "property_name": "fromState",
        "property_value": "app"
      },
      {
        "operator": "not_contains",
        "property_name": "user_email",
        "property_value": "@giblib.com"
      },
      {
        "operator": "not_contains",
        "property_name": "fromState",
        "property_value": "app.auth_postregister"
      }
    ],
    "analysis_type": "count_unique",
    "timezone": "US/Pacific",
    "group_by": null,
    "force_exact": null,
    "timeframe": "this_2_months",
    "target_property": "user_id",
    "interval": "monthly",
    "event_collection": "user-page-access"
  },
  "run_information": null,
  "metadata": {
    "visualization": {
      "chart_type": "areachart"
    },
    "display_name": "Monthly Active Users"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console when you do this? 

You should be able to use a saved query in a chart. It gets a response the same way as an ad hoc query.

Comment: No, I didn't get any error from savedQueries.get("monthly-active-users" , the chart show "No data to display" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you did not include the `Keen.ready()` function. Also, I recommend using `client.run` instead of `client.get` because it runs the query and gets the result.

I went ahead and created an example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pn14bs0L/2/

```
Keen.ready(function() {

  client.run("test-saved-query", function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      // there was an error
    } else {
      var chart1 = new Keen.Dataviz()
        .el(document.getElementById('my_chart'))
        .chartType("areachart")
        .colors(["#6ab975"])
        .title("Monthly Active Users")
        .prepare();

      chart1
        .data(response)
        .render();
    }
  });

});
```

You can see this working with some test data in the JSFiddle.

Note: I assumed you were using keen-js here and not keen-dataviz.js.

Comment: This works good, but isn't there a way to modify the timeframe of the response obj to chart for a different timeframe??

Comment: A timeframe other than the one the saved query has?

Comment: Yes, I want query with different timeframe than what's saved.  Is that possible?

Comment: You would need to create another saved query or just use an ad-hoc query. You could possibly get the saved query definition (https://keen.io/docs/api/#getting-a-saved-query-definition) and then create a new one from there.